# Change AssemblyName via MSBuild Target

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

I am trying to configure an MSBuild target, in my Project.csproj file. The target, called "Test" is called with the following command:

**msbuild.exe /target:Test**

However, I cannot figure out how to change the AssemblyName (original assembly name is MyProject), for this target. My code looks like this:

```
<Target Name="Test">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PublishUrl>D:\PublishLocation\ClickOnce Setup\</PublishUrl>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <MSBuild Projects="$(ProjLocation)\$(ProjectName).csproj" Properties="ProductName=$(ProductName) (Test); AssemblyName=MyProjectTest; PublishUrl=$(PublishUrl)" Targets="Publish" />
  <ItemGroup>
    <SetupFiles Include="$(ProjPublishLocation)\*.*" />
    <UpdateFiles Include="$(ProjPublishLocation)\Application Files\**\*.*" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Copy SourceFiles="@(SetupFiles)" DestinationFolder="D:\PublishLocation\ClickOnce Setup\" />
  <Copy SourceFiles="@(UpdateFiles)" DestinationFolder="D:\PublishLocation\ClickOnce Setup\Application Files\%(RecursiveDir)" />
</Target>
```

If I remove the `AssemblyName=MyProjectTest;` from the code, it works fine. If I run it as above, I get the following error:

> "C:\Users\...\MyProject\MyProject.csproj"
>   (Test target) (1) ->
>   "C:\Users\...\MyProject\MyProject.csproj"
>   (Publish target) (1:2 ) ->
>
> (CoreCompile target) ->
>   Models\SessionModel.cs(207,51): error CS1528: Expected ; or = (cannot
>   specify constructor arguments in declaration) [
>   C:\Users\...\MyProject\MyProject.csproj]
>
> (...and a lot more, which is more or less the same)

**UPDATE**

I found some more, perhaps more interesting, warnings in the build output:

> "C:\Users\...\MyProject\MyProject.csproj"
>   (Fast target) (1) ->
>   "C:\Users\...\MyProject.csproj"
>   (Publish target) (1:2 ) -> (ResolveAssemblyReferences target) ->
>   C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1820,5):
>   warning MSB3277: 
>   Found conflicts between different versions of the
>   same dependent assembly that could not be resolved.  These reference
>   conflicts a re listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to
>   detailed. [C:\Users\...\MyProject\MyProject.csproj]

It might be worth mentioning, that I have older versions published in the publish location, in which the assembly name was not changed. Can this cause the conflict I see...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was, that I had included `System.net.http.dll` as a file in my project. This was set to **Content** as build actions. When I changed it to **Embedded resource**, it started working.

Answer (score 1):

> Change AssemblyName via MSBuild Target

According to your `Test` target and [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50502570/change-assembly-name-for-build-settings-in-csproj), I have created a sample app to test this issue with following scripts and MSBuild command line `msbuild.exe /target:Test`:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ProjLocation>$(ProjectDir)</ProjLocation>
    <ProjLocationReleaseDir>$(ProjLocation)\bin\Debug</ProjLocationReleaseDir>
    <ProjPublishLocation>$(ProjLocationReleaseDir)\app.publish</ProjPublishLocation>
    <DeploymentFolder>D:\PublishFolder\Test\</DeploymentFolder>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="Test" DependsOnTargets="Clean">
    <MSBuild Projects="$(ProjLocation)\$(ProjectName).csproj" Properties="ProductName=$(ProductName) (Test); AssemblyName=MyProjectTest; PublishUrl=$(PublishUrl)" Targets="Publish" />

    <ItemGroup>
      <SetupFiles Include="$(ProjPublishLocation)\*.*" />
      <UpdateFiles Include="$(ProjPublishLocation)\Application Files\**\*.*" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(SetupFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(DeploymentFolder)\Public Test\" />
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(UpdateFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(DeploymentFolder)\Public Test\Application Files\%(RecursiveDir)" />
  </Target>
```

It works fine without any issue, and assembly name was also changed:

[image]

So this issue should be more related to the error CS1528 in the `SessionModel.cs` file and `warning MSB3277`. To resolve the CS1528 error, you can check the document [Compiler Error CS1528](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs1528) for some more details.

And for the `warning MSB3277`, you can change the "MSBuild project build output verbosity" to "Detailed" to check the reference conflicts and resolve this conflicts. you can see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45444112/consider-app-config-remapping-of-assembly-with-no-app-config-mapping/45454885#45454885) for some details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. I am quite confused about all the reported errors in e.g. SessionModel.cs, since the application builds fine, when I build it "normally" through Visual Studio. It seems to be a ClickOnce problem only...

Comment: @Noceo, Yes, you can also create a new blank project to test this issue. But since I could not reproduce those two error on my side, I could not give a directly answer for this issue. Or you can provide a sample to reproduce sample or steps, then I will keep follow it.

Comment: While you might not be able to tell me exactly what the problem is, you did actually tell me, what the problem **is not**. So you have been very helpful :-). I am still stuck on exactly what is causing the problem, but I will update my question, if I find something significant.